# Get a document from MongoDB and place in an html form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb, angular

Could you please suggest me what functionality I should use to get a document (containing a few lines of text) in a MongoDB collection and place it in an html form using JavaScript/Angular?

So, first I need to query the MongoDB from inside an angular script. Is there a simple way to do this, like for example in python, using pymongo to connect to a database?

And second I need to place the output of the query to an html form. Seems easy, but are there any bottlenecks I can face?

Sorry for silly question - this is my second day of web-development

Comment: there is if you write one

Comment: thank you and sorry for the silly question - this is my second day of web-development

Comment: Creating  client-side and server-side apps in your "second day of web-development"? You are very brave...!

Comment: @Ram I spent the first day figuring out the client side and the server one is for today. I will manage. My word...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly for getting data from database you need to write server side code. You may write it in nodejs or any other language of your choice. Then in that code you have to make query to database and expose that data using REST apis. Then inside of your angularjs application you will have to consume that rest API and then show the data onto the html page. 
Happy learning. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much